# Determine if the current branch is an orphan

Tags: git

I am working on the [difflint](https://github.com/endlessm/difflint) project and have an open issue where the program fails when the current state is that of an orphaned branch (which could happen in a few different ways -- the most common of which would be when you are creating a new repository via `git init`.) It is failing because it is trying to use `git stash` which doesn't work if there is no prior history.

I am looking for a way to programatically determine if the current branch has no history.  One option would be to run `git show-branch` and look for the string `"No revs to be shown."` but that seems a bit hacky.  I'm hoping for a solution that seems less brittle, such as something to determine the longest history path from a given state; I could simply check if it is 0.  Are there any less brittle/hacky ways to detect if there is no previous history?

(Porcelain commands are acceptable, if necessary.  The project already relies on them.)

Comment: `git rev-parse --verify HEAD`

Comment: `fatal: Needed a single revision`

Comment: You can add `--quiet` if you do not like this error message.

Comment: @PetSerAl Oh wow.  I just read the docs for that option and this is an excellent answer to my problem. It will only error out if HEAD doesn't exist. Please convert this to an answer and I'll accept it!